# How do I select reCAPTCHA challenge for invisible reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, bots, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am trying to implement google invisible reCAPTCHA (v2) on my site.
I want to customize the challenge whenever it is thrown to user.
How do I select which challenge to show to fraudulent users/bots?

I want to show arithmetic challenge instead of selecting the lights in images grid, I'm not able to find the option anywhere. Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google doesn't offer this as an option I *think* it's for a security reason as making it only digits will make it easier for OCRs to figure the answer easier as opposed to alphabet + numbers

I can't figure out a reason why you would only show numbers other than making it easier for the users If so you could check out [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) it provides a better user experience as

> reCAPTCHA v3 returns a score for each request without user friction. The score is based on interactions with your site and enables you to take appropriate action for your site.

Instead of the usual challenges.

Comment: Its not digits or numbers, there is a challenge that user needs to solve like 8+2 = [].
I don't want user to select the boxes in images grid

Comment: it's the same idea OCR can figure out the numbers and then it's easy to solve the equation. Maybe you could edit your question to elaborate why do you need to provide only arithmetic challenges so people could think of alternatives for reCAPTCHA but as of right now it's not possible to specify what challenges should appear to the user when using reCAPTCHA